# how to multiple variables in for loop range python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I can't seem to get the following for loop in range to work. This is the entire code. Perhaps is more helpful to post the entire program

```
import pandas as pd
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
from alpha_vantage.foreignexchange import ForeignExchange
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import time
import numpy as np
import os

api_key="xxx"

cc = ForeignExchange(key=api_key, output_format="pandas", indexing_type= "date")
#ti = TechIndicators(key= api_key, output_format="pandas", indexing_type= "date")
ts = TimeSeries(key= api_key, output_format="pandas", indexing_type= "date")

filePath = r"/Users/LaCasa/PycharmProjects/Forex_Breakout_Backtest_15MIN/forex_pairs.xlsx"
filePath1 = r"/Users/LaCasa/PycharmProjects/Forex_Breakout_Backtest_15MIN/"
stocklist = pd.read_excel(filePath, engine='openpyxl')
stocklist = stocklist.head(5)

exportList = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Base','Quote'])

for i in stocklist.index:
    fx_from = str(stocklist["fx_from"][i])
    fx_to = str(stocklist["fx_to"][i])
    data_fx, meta_data_fx = cc.get_currency_exchange_intraday(from_symbol=fx_from,to_symbol=fx_to,interval='15min',
                                                              outputsize='full')
    data_fx.sort_index(inplace=True)

    total_df = data_fx
    total_df["BASE"] = fx_from
    total_df["QUOTE"] = fx_to
    total_df.rename(columns={'1. open': 'OPEN','2. high': 'HIGH','3. low': 'LOW','4. close':'CLOSE'},inplace=True)

    result = []
    train_size = 0.6
    n_forward = 5

    total_df['Forward Close'] = total_df['CLOSE'].shift(-n_forward)
    total_df['Forward Return'] = (total_df['Forward Close'] - total_df['CLOSE']) / total_df['CLOSE']

    for sma_length, sma_length2, sma_length3 in range(10, 200, 10):
        print(sma_length)
        total_df["MA1"] = round(total_df["CLOSE"].rolling(window=sma_length).mean(), 5)
        total_df["SD1"] = round(total_df["CLOSE"].rolling(window=sma_length).std(), 5)
        total_df["z1"] = round((total_df["CLOSE"].sub(total_df["MA1"])).div(total_df["SD1"]), 3)
        total_df["Z1"] = round(total_df["z1"].rolling(window=1).mean(), 3)
        total_df["MAZ1"] = round(total_df["Z1"].rolling(window=3).mean(), 5)
        total_df["SDMA1"] = round(total_df["SD1"].rolling(window=sma_length).mean(), 5)
        total_df["STD1"] = round(total_df["SD1"].rolling(window=sma_length).std(), 5)
        total_df["zd1"] = round((total_df["SD1"].sub(total_df["SDMA1"])).div(total_df["STD1"]), 3)
        total_df["ZDEV1"] = round(total_df["zd1"].rolling(window=1).mean(), 3)
        total_df["MAZDEV1"] = round(total_df["ZDEV1"].rolling(window=3).mean(), 3)

        total_df["MA2"] = round(total_df["CLOSE"].rolling(window=sma_length2).mean(), 5)
        total_df["SD2"] = round(total_df["CLOSE"].rolling(window=sma_length2).std(), 5)
        total_df["z2"] = round((total_df["CLOSE"].sub(total_df["MA2"])).div(total_df["SD2"]), 3)
        total_df["Z2"] = round(total_df["z2"].rolling(window=1).mean(), 3)
        total_df["MAZ2"] = round(total_df["Z2"].rolling(window=3).mean(), 5)
        total_df["SDMA2"] = round(total_df["SD2"].rolling(window=sma_length2).mean(), 5)
        total_df["STD2"] = round(total_df["SD2"].rolling(window=sma_length2).std(), 5)
        total_df["zd2"] = round((total_df["SD2"].sub(total_df["SDMA2"])).div(total_df["STD2"]), 3)
        total_df["ZDEV2"] = round(total_df["zd2"].rolling(window=1).mean(), 3)
        total_df["MAZDEV2"] = round(total_df["ZDEV2"].rolling(window=3).mean(), 3)

        total_df["MA3"] = round(total_df["CLOSE"].rolling(window=sma_length3).mean(), 5)
        total_df["SD3"] = round(total_df["CLOSE"].rolling(window=sma_length3).std(), 5)
        total_df["z3"] = round((total_df["CLOSE"].sub(total_df["MA3"])).div(total_df["SD3"]), 3)
        total_df["Z3"] = round(total_df["z3"].rolling(window=1).mean(), 3)
        total_df["MAZ3"] = round(total_df["Z3"].rolling(window=3).mean(), 5)
        total_df["SDMA3"] = round(total_df["SD3"].rolling(window=sma_length3).mean(), 5)
        total_df["STD3"] = round(total_df["SD3"].rolling(window=sma_length3).std(), 5)
        total_df["zd3"] = round((total_df["SD3"].sub(total_df["SDMA3"])).div(total_df["STD3"]), 3)
        total_df["ZDEV3"] = round(total_df["zd3"].rolling(window=1).mean(), 3)
        total_df["MAZDEV3"] = round(total_df["ZDEV3"].rolling(window=3).mean(), 3)

        # BREAKOUT
        total_df['input1'] = [int(x) for x in total_df['Z1'] > 2]
        total_df['input2'] = [int(x) for x in total_df['Z1'].shift(1) < 2]

        # VOLATILITY
        total_df['input3'] = [int(x) for x in (total_df['ZDEV2'] > total_df['MAZDEV2'])]

        #total_df = total_df.dropna(subset=["MAZDEV2"], inplace=False)

        #VOLATILITY #2
        total_df['input4'] = [int(x) for x in (total_df['ZDEV3'] > total_df['MAZDEV3'])]
        total_df['input5'] = [int(x) for x in total_df['ZDEV3'] < 1]
        #
        # #TREND
        total_df['input6'] = [int(x) for x in (total_df['Z3'] > total_df['MAZ3'])]
        #total_df['input7'] = [int(x) for x in total_df['Z3'] > 1]
        print(total_df['input4'])
        training = total_df.head(int(train_size * total_df.shape[0]))
        test = total_df.tail(int((1 - train_size) * total_df.shape[0]))

        tr_returns = training[training['input1' and 'input2' and 'input3' and 'input4' and 'input5' and 'input6'] == 1]['Forward Return']
        test_returns = test[test['input1' and 'input2' and 'input3' and 'input4' and 'input5' and 'input6'] == 1]['Forward Return']

        mean_forward_return_training = tr_returns.mean()
        mean_forward_return_test = test_returns.mean()

        pvalue = ttest_ind(tr_returns, test_returns, equal_var=False)[1]
        result.append({
            'base': fx_from,
            'quote': fx_to,
            'sma_length': sma_length,
            'sma_length2': sma_length2,
            'sma_length3': sma_length3,
            'training_forward_return': mean_forward_return_training,
            'test_forward_return': mean_forward_return_test,
            'p-value': pvalue
        })

    result.sort(key=lambda x: -x['training_forward_return'])
    print(result[0])
    time.sleep(15)
    newFile = os.path.dirname(filePath1) + "/period.xlsx"
    writer = ExcelWriter(newFile)
    total_df.to_excel(writer, "Sheet1", float_format="%.7f")
    writer.save()
```

error: TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object

Ideally I like to find the best rolling window for each of the ZScore formulas you see above but don't know how to make the loop work

Comment: What values do you expect to see in the loop variables? `in range(20,500)` gives you one `int` every iteration, you can't unpack it.

Comment: `range()` generates single value in every loop - you have to use `for value in range(20, 500)`.

Comment: Do you want to try all possible combinations of 3 values in this range? If that's the case, you can have a look at `itertools.product` - but note that there will be more than 111 millions combinations.

Comment: `range(20, 500)` returns a sequence like this: `[20, 21, 22, ..., 500]`.  So every iteration you get one integer at a time, which cannot be unpacked in to a 3-tuple (`sma_*` variables).  Which is exactly what the error message says.  This is equivalent to: `x, y, z = 1`.

Comment: I have updated the question with the full code so everyone can see what I am trying to accomplish

Comment: It actually makes it less clear to see all of this to be honest. What values you trying to get for your 3 sma lengths?

Comment: @nihilok the idea is to calculate the sma with a sma_length between 10 & 200. With each sma_length I want the program to go to the rest of the code and calculate the rest of the indicators (inputs) which change based on sma_length and perform the trading simulation to determine which sma_length combination among all 6 inputs is most profitable

Comment: @RicardoDacosta I have added some more examples to my answer which should help you.

Comment: @nihilok ok thank you! This is very helpful indeed. The reason why I think I need 3 different sma_lenght variables is to determine at the end in result[] which sma_length for each Z1, Z2 & Z3 as they might be different on all 3. I thought one way would be to add the sma_length to the Column as total_df["Z1_" + str(sma_length)] and then be able to (i don't know how) identify the column with the end in result[]  like 'sma_length':  Z1_50 for example which will tell me the sma_length that triggered the signal for Z1 was 50. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, you are trying to unpack a single integer into 3 values.

The iterator `range(20, 500)` only returns a single integer on each iteration.

```
for i in range(20, 50):
   do_something(i)
   do_something_else(i)
   do_a_third_thing(i)

# i is the same single integer in each case
```

Other than that I'm not sure what you are trying to do. If you need 3 different values you could use an iterator with 3 different values. You could do something like:

```
for i, j, k in [(a1, b1, c1), (a2, b2, c2), ...]:
    ...
```

but there have to be three values to 'unpack'.

EDIT:
As far as I can see from your script there might be two things you could try...

Maybe removing `sma_length2` and `sma_length3` variables entirely, since the nature of a for loop is that it will iterate over the values it is given, so you will get all of the results within the range you define.

Something like this:

```
for sma_length in range(10, 201):      # remember that with the iterable returned from range, the last value will not be included.
        print(sma_length)
        total_df["MA1"] = round(total_df["CLOSE"].rolling(window=sma_length).mean(), 5)
        total_df["SD1"] = round(total_df["CLOSE"].rolling(window=sma_length).std(), 5)
        total_df["z1"] = round((total_df["CLOSE"].sub(total_df["MA1"])).div(total_df["SD1"]), 3)
        total_df["Z1"] = round(total_df["z1"].rolling(window=1).mean(), 3)
        total_df["MAZ1"] = round(total_df["Z1"].rolling(window=3).mean(), 5)
        total_df["SDMA1"] = round(total_df["SD1"].rolling(window=sma_length).mean(), 5)
        total_df["STD1"] = round(total_df["SD1"].rolling(window=sma_length).std(), 5)
        total_df["zd1"] = round((total_df["SD1"].sub(total_df["SDMA1"])).div(total_df["STD1"]), 3)
        total_df["ZDEV1"] = round(total_df["zd1"].rolling(window=1).mean(), 3)
        total_df["MAZDEV1"] = round(total_df["ZDEV1"].rolling(window=3).mean(), 3)
```

Since you are testing all of those values between 10 and 200 anyway with this loop, I'm not sure why you need the other 2 `sma_length` variables.

One thing to note separately about the code above is that you have some "magic numbers" which will be the same on every iteration.

When you write "`window=3`" or "`window=1`" for example, this will never change and you are just wastefully recalculating the same value for every loop.

If, however, you actually want 3 different sma_lengths at the same time you could use the `zip()` inbuilt function to create an iterable as described above (a sequence of tuples of length 3).

You could do something like this:

```
iterable = zip(range(100), range(100, 200), range(200, 300))

for a, b, c in iterable:
    print((a, b, c))

# (0, 100, 200)
# (1, 101, 201)
# (2, 102, 202)
# ... etc.
```

But as I said, I think you can do what you require with only one variable as in the previous example. Hope this helps.